# where should timezone processing be done, on server or on client?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Where do you process timezone calculations, is it better do do it on the server or on the client using a javascript library like moment?

Currently I am doing it on server using this library:
https://github.com/camroncade/timezone

and these two:

```
public function getPublishedAtAttribute()
{
    if(Auth::guest()) {
        return $this->attributes['published_at']->format('Y-m-d\TH:i\Z');
    }
    else {
        $timezone = Auth::user()->timezone;
        if(isset($this->attributes['published_at']))
            return Timezone::convertFromUTC($this->attributes['published_at'], $timezone, 'Y-m-d H:i');
        else
            return null;
    }
}

public function setPublishedAtAttribute($published_at)
{
    if($published_at) {
        $published_at_temp = new Carbon($published_at, Auth::user()->timezone);
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Timezone::convertToUTC($published_at_temp->addSeconds(59), Auth::user()->timezone);
    }
    elseif(!$this->published_at) {
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::now();
    }
}
```

Are there any minuses for doing it on the server or any pluses doing it on the client?

Which is better approach?

Comment: Always in the client side. This way you not only account for the user changing locations (as explained in the answers), but also keeps the data all in one format in the database and keeps the server from having todo extra (unnecessary) processes.

Answer (score 2):

Store always server time. It is easy to deal with, so you can give an easy opportunity to change timezone (just change one field, not all existing records).

Then convert every time output in view . Create simple `timeHelper` which is aware of current user and his timezone and inject it in view `@inject('timehelper', 'App\Services\Timehelper')` and `{{ $timehelper->out($model->created_at) }}`. In `out()` just apply user's timezone. Sometimes it is easy to output raw time with server timezone and then convert it via `moment.js`, using some attribute: `<span ts="150...">20:20 20th July</span>`

You have to store client's time just in cases like when you have strict billing, based on users' local time.

Comment: hi, if I output raw time with server timezone and then convert it via moment.js does that mean I can detect user timezone with moment and then convert to that timezone? For example if a visitor to the website is not logged in I can via moment detect timezone and convert all times on the page to correct timezone?

Comment: Right, moment is aware of user's timezone, look at `moment().utcOffset()`, for example. So you just need a simple script to change times on any page.

Comment: how about using this: moment.tz.guess() to get the correct timezone, it should work on most browsers

Comment: Yep, you can use it as well. utcOffset returns digit of a timezone, guess returns its name.

Comment: just to report, this did not work correctly: moment.tz(this.initPublishAtDate,moment.tz.guess()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), input time was in UFC and to convert back what I got from DB this worked:
moment.utc(this.initPublishAtDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') that gave me back the correct time that I published the model at.

Answer (score 1):

On the client, you have to account for a user taking their laptop with them when they travel to a different timezone. Now there's the server time, the user's local time, and the user's laptop time. And that's before you factor in any latency in a time-sensitive transaction.

Comment: ok if I do it on the client, do all modern browsers support detection of users timezone so that library like moment can detect this and then send correct timezone and date to the server?

Comment: As I understand it, the timezone is reported by the operating system. Say you live in NYC, which is US Eastern Standard -05:00. If you took your computer westward to Illinois, your *physical* timezone would be US Central Standard -06:00, but if you don't update your OS clock/timezone, it can't just "know".

Answer (score 0):

Do it on server side. I think it would be more "beautiful"

Comment: What do you mean by beautiful? Please consider adding some solid arguments for this decision.

Comment: @Kuba ... ok and what arguments have you? Just clicking minus on answers!

Comment: One could argue many things, for example, will you be updating the date in the server if the user changes locations? What about data consistency? Having different timezones stored in the data makes it hard to manipulate it. It's best if dates in the db are kept to match the server's time.